# AngularJs Injector Module Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

i'm new in AngularJs (started an couple hours ago) and i'm trying to complete the AngularJs in 60 minutes'ish tutorial. But i got stucked on the first controllers example.
This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>Angular Js</title>
    <meta charset="iso-8859-1">

</head>
<body>

    <div class="container" data-ng-controller="CustomerController">
        <input type="text" ng-model="name"> {{name}}

        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers">
                {{ cust.name}} - {{cust.city}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.17/angular.js"></script>

    <script>
        function CustomerController($scope) 
        {   
            $scope.customers = [
                {name:'Leonardo', city:'Phoenix'}, 
                {name:'Michelangelo', city:'Los Angeles'},
                {name:'Rafael', city:'New York'}, 
                {name:'Donatello', city:'Texas City'}
            ];
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the error i got from the ChromeDev Console:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify th...<omitted>...2) angular.js:78
(anonymous function) angular.js:78
(anonymous function) angular.js:4003
forEach angular.js:328
loadModules angular.js:3964
createInjector angular.js:3904
doBootstrap angular.js:1500
bootstrap angular.js:1515
angularInit angular.js:1427
(anonymous function) angular.js:23362
trigger angular.js:2653
(anonymous function) angular.js:2933
forEach angular.js:328
eventHandler angular.js:2932
```

As a newbie, I dont want to get into injector or modules and stuff. Since the tutorial is get to work only with this piece of code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you defined ng-app="myApp" but you didn't define any module named "myApp", so just use ng-app.

second, seems like the angular version you used 1.3.0-beta.17 doesn't work if you don't declare a module like this

> angular.module("myApp", [])

if you want to to make the example you posted work, use a different angular version, like 1.2.5

here's a working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zelapebo/1/edit?html,js,output) of your code

Answer (score 1):

I think you should always declare at least one module.

Try:

```
<script>

    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    function CustomerController($scope) 
    {   
        $scope.customers = [
            {name:'Leonardo', city:'Phoenix'}, 
            {name:'Michelangelo', city:'Los Angeles'},
            {name:'Rafael', city:'New York'}, 
            {name:'Donatello', city:'Texas City'}
        ];
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You should probably inject in the controller too, or that still won't help him get going.

Comment: That depends on the angular version. Take this fiddle for instance http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/HB7LU/

Comment: Well, it's the latest version 1.3.x

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 solutions:

***First***, as your error says: "**Module 'myApp' is not available!**". You need first to define the module `myApp`, so that angular could *instantiate* it. Then add your controller's constructor function to `myApp` module [using the `.controller()` method](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller#setting-up-the-initial-state-of-a-scope-object).

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('CustomerController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
        $scope.customers = [{
            name: 'Leonardo',
            city: 'Phoenix'
        }, {
            name: 'Michelangelo',
            city: 'Los Angeles'
        }, {
            name: 'Rafael',
            city: 'New York'
        }, {
            name: 'Donatello',
            city: 'Texas City'
        }];
    }
]);
```

***[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/kiqoyave/1/edit)***

***Second***, just remove `myApp` from your `<html>` tag and everything will work just fine

```
<html ng-app="">
```

***[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/fasimora/1/edit)***